# setInterval and an event loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Say I have some `setInterval` invocation with 10ms as an argument. I fire it up, and have some JavaScript code that takes 25ms to complete. After 10ms, the first interval callback is queued up. After 20ms, there's nothing additional queued up because (the Web API logic I presume, if this is where `setInterval` ticking occurs, decides this) one instance of a `setInterval` is already queued.

Now, at 25ms, when the main logic complete, `setInterval` starts and it takes, say, 10ms complete (so by the time it completes, 35ms would pass from program execution). At 30ms, while the `setInterval` callback is in the stack and executing, another tick occurs. What happens now? Will another instance of `setInterval` callback queue go in the event queue? Or will the browser environment see that there is an interval instance in the stack executing and skip pushing a new instance to the event queue, thus making the next `setInterval` instance tick at 40ms *finally* push a new callback?

Comment: Test it out using console.log, see what happens

Comment: Can you show the your script here?

Comment: There is no way to make a code to test this, unless using some highly accurate performance tools with which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: `After 20ms, there's nothing queued up` - your assumption is incorrect - every 10ms (approximately) the callback is queued on to the event loop, regardless.

Comment: @JaromandaX my mistake, I meant there's nothing "additional" queued up. Just the 1 interval that was initially queued up in the 10th ms.

Comment: If a callback to be invoked is still in the queue - then another one will not be added until the former has not been enqueued. So, in short - the same callback is guaranteed to not be invoked more frequently than the delay interval.

Comment: @zerkms my question is what happens if that callback is executed, already in the stack, and WHILE that is happening, another setInterval tick occurs? Will a new callback be added to the queue?

Comment: JS is single threaded, nothing can happen while some other piece of code is being executed. So the tick will happen *after* the current run has completed and it will successfully schedule another run (since there is no reason to not to) http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: @daremkd: It's not too difficult to code a test for this. And you don't need highly accurate performance tools to do it. Since the time intervals are only in ms you can do it with pure js: https://jsfiddle.net/slebetman/o55tcsy6/

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, JavaScript is single threaded. To demonstrate this, I tested this code:

```
var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (count >= 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    var start = Date.now();
    var number = ++count;
    console.log("Call #" + number + " begin: " + start);

    // Delay for 250 ms
    while (Date.now() - start < 250) {}

    var end = Date.now();
    console.log("Call #" + number + " end: " + end + " Interval: " + (end - start));
}, 1);
```

And it outputs:

```
Call #1 begin: 1453087997262
Call #1 end: 1453087997512 Interval: 250
Call #2 begin: 1453087997522
Call #2 end: 1453087997772 Interval: 250
Call #3 begin: 1453087997777
Call #3 end: 1453087998027 Interval: 250
Call #4 begin: 1453087998027
Call #4 end: 1453087998277 Interval: 250
Call #5 begin: 1453087998277
Call #5 end: 1453087998527 Interval: 250
```

If JavaScript was multithreaded, the output would look more like:

```
Call #1 begin
Call #2 begin
Call #3 begin
Call #4 begin
Call #5 begin
// Approximate 245-250ms delay
Call #1 end Interval: 250
Call #2 end Interval: 250
Call #3 end Interval: 250
Call #4 end Interval: 250
Call #5 end Interval: 250
```

A JSFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/126kkjwh/